# How to pass DOM val() and html() to polygon options in drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I an trying to pass some values from DOM `.val()` and `.html()` like this:

```
$("#drawPolygon").on("click",function(){
    var polyName = $("#polyDatasetName").val();
    var polyColor = $("#polyFillColor").val();
    var polyTranc = ($("#polyTrancparency").html()).slice(2);
    var polyBorderColor = $("#polyBorderColor").val();
    var polyBorderSize = $("#polyBorderSize").html();
    var polyBorderTranc = ($("#polyBorderTransparency").html()).slice(2);
 });
```

I tried to alert the result which all where perfectly correct but when I pass them as PolygonOptions options like:

```
 polygonOptions: {
          fillColor: polyColor,
          fillOpacity: (polyFillColor/100),
          strokeColor: polyBorderColor,
          strokeWeight:polyBorderSize,
          clickable: false,
          editable: true,
          zIndex: 1
   }
```

I am  getting following error message:

[image]

Why is this happening and how I can solve it? Here is the code which I have for Drawing Manager:

```
<script>
var map;
var drawingManager
$(document).ready(function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(49.241943, -122.889318);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 
    $("#drawPolygon").on("click",function(){
        var polyName = $("#polyDatasetName").val();
        var polyColor = $("#polyFillColor").val();
        var polyTranc = ($("#polyTrancparency").html()).slice(2);
        var polyBorderColor = $("#polyBorderColor").val();
        var polyBorderSize = $("#polyBorderSize").html();
        var polyBorderTranc = ($("#polyBorderTransparency").html()).slice(2);
     });

    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
            google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE]
        },
       
     polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: polyColor,
      fillOpacity: (polyFillColor/100),
      strokeColor: polyBorderColor,
      strokeWeight:polyBorderSize,
      clickable: false,
      editable: true,
      zIndex: 1
    }
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you define the polyColor(and all the other variables) locally inside of an anonymous function which is executed when you click on the specified div and as soon as the function is executed, those variables are dicarded.

Meaning that when you are creating object polygonOptions, those variables are not defined(they do not exist anymore).

To solve this, define those variables inside of document.ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var polyName;
    var polyColor;
    var polyTranc;
    var polyBorderColor;
    var polyBorderSize;
    var polyBorderTranc;
    ...

});
```

Then on click event just assign values to these variables:

```
$("#drawPolygon").on("click",function() {
    polyName = $("#polyDatasetName").val();
    polyColor = $("#polyFillColor").val();
    polyTranc = ($("#polyTrancparency").html()).slice(2);
    polyBorderColor = $("#polyBorderColor").val();
    polyBorderSize = $("#polyBorderSize").html();
    polyBorderTranc = ($("#polyBorderTransparency").html()).slice(2);
}
```

And it should work as expected now.

Comment: Hi Matus,, Thanks for your comment, actually I am able to draw the polygon now but it is not taking any style from the setting!

Comment: Try to print the object to console when created to see if it has the specified properties.

Comment: Ok I have just realized. Put all the code(drawing manager and polygonOptions inside the click function).

Comment: Yeah that was the issue , thanks it was very helpful